# Is $\log|f|$ continuous or just upper semicontinuous?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

I have read that $\log|f|$ is subharmonic if $f$ is holomorphic, meaning that it is upper semicontinuos and satisfies the local submean inequality. But is the function also continuous? I am having trouble how to deal with the infinity thing...

Comment: Yes, if you are careful about dealing with zeros of $f$.

Comment: What exactly to you mean? When $f=0$, then $\log|f|=-\infty$...